# struct task_struct members?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

i have written  module which reads and write on /proc file and is working fine but want to use permissions with it when i make the function for permissions shown below its gives me error (basically i want every one could read the file but only root could write in it).

```
int my_permission(struct inode *inode, int op)
{
if(op == 4||(op == 2 && current->euid = 0))  //euid is not a member of task_struct
return 0;
return -EACCES;
}
const  struct inode_operations my_iops = {
.permission = my_permission,
};
```

but its giving me error as follow:

```
/home/karan/practice/procf/testproc1.c: In function ‘my_permission’:
/home/karan/practice/procf/testproc1.c:50:32: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘euid’
```

I think there is other member in task_struct which points to user id . I am interested in solution as well as description of task_struct members field used for.

regards
karan

Comment: Did you look up on http://kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/

Comment: @Shiplu        i want something specific about task_struct and nothing else.........though the link is good.

Comment: Google "linux lxr", find the `struct task_struct` definition, see what fields you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See include/linux/cred.h:

```
    #define current_euid()          (current_cred_xxx(euid))  
    #define current_cred_xxx(xxx)                   \
    ({                                              \
            current_cred()->xxx;                    \
    })
```

and so current_euid() falls back on current_cred():

```
    /**
     * current_cred - Access the current task's subjective credentials
     *
     * Access the subjective credentials of the current task.  RCU-safe,
     * since nobody else can modify it.
     */
    #define current_cred() \
            rcu_dereference_protected(current->cred, 1)
```

So for you problem, to do effective UID comparison, take a look at /fs/exec.c:

```
    if (current_euid() == current_uid() && current_egid() == current_gid())
    bprm->cred->euid = current_euid();
            bprm->cred->euid = inode->i_uid
```

contrast with your program:

```
    if (current_euid() == 0)
```

which means even if the user is not logined with UID=0, it will be treated effecively as UID==0?   Sounds dangerous

Answer (score 1):

```
if(op == 4||(op == 2 && current->euid = 0))
```

1. Are you sure you want to assign 0 to `current->euid` ? Maybe you meant to compare.
2. Where is `current` defined? I'm assuming its a `struct task_struct` but if so, is `euid` a pointer? or is `current` a pointer to a `struct task_struct`? If neither `euid` nor `current` are pointers just replace `->` with `.`

Kind of out of topic, but:

```
const  struct inode_operations my_iops = {
.permission = my_permission,
};
```

Is the kind of thing that would make a programmer maintaining your code want to kill you in your sleep. Use `typedef` for readability. Don't declare global variables; if you do, don't declare them after a function. When declaring a struct with partial assignments its more readable to do it after the declaration.

I know its a test, or an incomplete code, or something no one will need to maintain. But you might want to read this in a couple of years, and when you do you'll spend twice as much trying to find the solution you are looking for. And you are posting this on SO where there are some style nazis, like myself, that will have problems to sleep this night after seeing a declaration like that.

Comment: Amazingly similar to [this](http://kerneltrap.org/node/1584) attempt to create a back door in the Linux kernel.

Comment: @whitelion            ok i could understand there would be some standards of writing codes .... but this code is something which i took from "the linux kernel programming guide" and in future i will try to your advices (so that you can sleep(just kidding)) ....but whats the solution.....

Comment: @whitelionV    its giving me error....error: request for member ‘euid’ in something not a structure or union

Comment: @whitelionV I realize this was 4 years ago now, but I'm also just learning kernel module programming, and what passes for bad in application development does not necessarily pass for bad in kernel module programming. It's a very different world, attempt no landing there.